# Resolve URLs for ASP.NET in jQuery?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

I would like to use "`~/`" and resolve on the client site.

For example, I would want to do this:

```
<a href="~/page.aspx">website link</a>
<img src="~/page.aspx" />
```

I would have my base URLs in ASP.NET like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var baseUrl = "<%= ResolveUrl("~/") %>";
</script>
```

Would I need a jQuery plugin for this or can this be a achieved with a chained command?

Comment: Are you generating these when the page is first rendered?  If so a `runat="server"` on those tags will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You could mass-replace the hrefs like this:

```
$('a').attr('href', function(index, oldValue) {
    return oldValue.replace('~/', baseUrl);
});
```

although the idea seems dangerous. What happens if javascript is disabled?

Comment: What if I do it on the server in the render output event? Is this not worth the performance hit or risks (whatever that could be)?